# Modal window not taking full 100 width

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I've a modal window that I want to take the full screen. I've got it to have 100% height but width isn't working. I've tried using min-width: 100%; but that gave more than 100%.

https://jsfiddle.net/k5adr0wc/

Just click on that img icon or the modal buttons. I've also tried

```css
.remodal-is-initialized {

  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
.remodal {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k5adr0wc/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following media query. You have a `max-width` of `700px`.
Remove it and it will work.

```
/* Media queries
   ========================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {

    .remodal {

        max-width: 700px;

    }

}
```

Also remove the `padding` on the `.remodal` class.

```
.remodal {

    width: 100%;

    margin-bottom: 10px;
    /* remove padding */
    padding: 35px;
    ...
```

There also seems to be a problem with the `#outer` div. You have overflowing content which produces a second scroll-bar on the right.

Comment: Thanks! There's a second scroll bar? How do I get rid of it? Should I use overflow: hidden; ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I also noticed at the bottom of the modal there's a little gap of just empty space? How do I get rid of that?